# Samsung syncmaster 2494 HM gives "Check Signal Cable" error in HDMI mode

Tags: windows-xp, video, display

My Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM is stuck in a `"Check Signal Cable"` error while in HDMI mode.

The screen is black.

How can I get my computer monitor screen to work again?

Answer (score 2):

I used my old cable with my new monitor, and who knew that all those pins actually meant something.

I found this one " they suggested me to change the cable to D-15 10 series." I went to the basement and got the cable that came with it

Guess what? it works when you use the stuff they tell you to use.

Brazzguy

Answer (score 0):

Here is somethings to check and also maybe more information.

From what I understand it's the same exact computer?

If yes... Check the following tests :

1 - Make sure that the monitor is really trying to check on the HDMI not on something else...

2 - If you have an other computer try to connect the monitor and any other device with the same cable to see if it works

2a - If not working then try an other cable option (example DVI connection) if it's working maybe either your HDMI cable or your HDMI input connector on your Monitor that could be defective

2b - If it's working with and other device... You have 1 more test to do... try if you can to connect the monitor in your current PC but with an other connector (if you have the option) if it's working then it might be your PC connector that is defective.

You should make some more testing to try and pin point what's happening...

If you know any Retail shop close to your place I would suggest to bring it to them sometime they will check for free to find the problem and see what they could do to fix it.

For now with the details given that's the only thing I can come up with :)

Regards

By the way I forgot one thing... I had a monitor that actually was not working properly with a mac... So it can happen that you won't be able to connect a working monitor no a different "pc"